# Objective-C how to show Cellular turned off alert

Tags: objective-c, alert

I am trying to show "Cellular Data is turned off" when there is no 3G or wifi

[image]

Comment: wonderful. Do you have any issue with your implementation? Show us your code and be a bit more specific in where you have a problem. This is not a general code-writing service See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want to show this system alert in my app whenever there is no internet.
It is shown in apple apps like Safari.

Answer (score 1):

There is a documentation available for this along with a sample project. 
You can refer to that [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_APLViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Reachability_APLViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_7).
Don't forget to add `SystemConfiguration` framework to your project.